# Android, how many fragments left

Tags: android, android-fragments

I need to add to my app the possibility to show a message as the user is leaving the app (i.e. would you like to leave ? yes-no)

I'm using fragments so I dont realy know which is the last to show the message on the "onBackPressed", so is there a way to know how many fragments are left or am I missing something ?

Comment: thanks !! getBackStackEntryCount() is what I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getSupportFragmentManager()getBackStackEntryCount()` was what I needed

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    if(getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0){
        DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                switch (which){
                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                    MainActivity.this.finish();
                    break;

                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                    break;
                }
            }
        };

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.leave_app)).setPositiveButton("Yes", dialogClickListener)
            .setNegativeButton("No", dialogClickListener).show();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `ViewPager` you can get currentFragment number using the `getCurrentItem() method` of ViewPager,

Then implement the `onBackPressed` method of `Activity`, also it will be called irrespective of whatever fragment the user is on, still you can compare the currentFragment number with the totalNumber of fragments and show a message.

```
private boolean exit = false;
    @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
                    // implement a logic on backPressed, I have added a logic
                    // it show a toast, if the user presses back again within
                    // three seconds, the activity closes.

                    if (exit)
                Home.this.finish();
            else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Press Back again to Exit.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                exit = true;
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        exit = false;
                    }
                }, 3 * 1000);

            } 

        }
```

Comment: thank you, but i wanted to show this just in my final fragment, the answer provided from @Tom Reznik was what I need, wich is "getBackStackEntryCount()"

Comment: @user2427819 okay, then you may get the current fragment id using the findFragmentById() method of FragmentManager, than compare it with the Fragment id of last fragment, and show a message.